# Comparision between two dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a calender and has following two scenarios:

**case - 1**

- current_month = 8 (aug)
- end_month = 10 (oct)
- current_year = 2017
- end_year = 2017

**case - 2**

- current_month = 8 (aug)
- end_month = 2 (feb)
- current_year = 2017
- end_year = 2018

When I click next month it should move only until "end_month". What should be the condition to satisfy both the cases:

```
if(condition)
  alert("Move to next month");
else
  alert("condition fail");
```

I have tried comparing start and end date objects, But I'm able to move one more month extra, which should not happen.
I have used the following conditions:

- cal_date = Tue Aug 01 2017 23:58:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
- $scope.edate = Wed Nov 15 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

  ```
  if (cal_date.getMonth() > $scope.edate.getMonth() + 1 || cal_date.getMonth() == $scope.edate.getMonth() || $scope.edate.getFullYear() <= new Date().getFullYear()) 

  if (cal_date.getMonth() > $scope.edate.getMonth() || cal_date.getMonth() == $scope.edate.getMonth()) 

  if (cal_date.getTime() < new Date(new Date($scope.edate) - 1)) {

  if (cal_date < $scope.edate) {
  ```

Comment: Are you wanting to move to the month that is shown for `end_month` when the user clicks next?

Comment: Why the PHP tag? Show what you tried already, even if it isn't working.

Comment: if(current_month < end_month || current_year < end_year)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Try using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: I voted to close the question because it doesn't show any code.  Also, "I have tried comparing start and end date objects, But I'm able to move one more month extra" implies that you have code which is written but flawed;  It is necessary to see that code to know why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Ohjay44 : No i want to move to next month and next month  till the end month ,If end month reaches  the condition should become false and should not move to next month.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create Date objects:

```
var current = new Date(year,month)
var end = new Date(year,month)
```

and then test:

```
if ( current<end )
```

That would probably be the simplest approach.